# Create an ms sql query to get data from tables belonging to different schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table named 'tbl_user' and this table exists under many schemas for example :

- schema1.tbl_user
- schema2.tbl_user

and so on. I would like to union all the data in these tables and get a single result and I cannot use any programming language because the environment I need to run it doesn't allow for it. Is there a way to accomplish this on sql server 2008 using stored procedures?

Edit : There are over a thousand schemas and schemas can be added and deleted as time goes.

Comment: Insert the union all records in a temp table ans use it.

Comment: used union all Operator record in a your table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using cursor, create the query dynamic and execute at when completed.

> You can add additional filter if you want to filter out the schema.

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(300)='userMaster'

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
  SELECT S.name
  from sys.schemas s
    inner join sys.sysusers u
        on u.uid = s.principal_id
order by s.name

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
         IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =@NAME 
                         AND  TABLE_NAME =@TABLE_NAME))
        BEGIN
        IF(LEN(@SQL)>0) 
        begin 
         SET @SQL =@SQL+' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ['+@NAME+'].['+@TABLE_NAME+']'    
        end
        ELSE
        begin
        SET @SQL ='SELECT * FROM ['+@NAME+'].['+@TABLE_NAME+']'
        end
        --PRINT @SQL
        END


      FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME
  END

CLOSE CUR

DEALLOCATE CUR 
PRINT @SQL
exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. When I try to select the required columns instead of  the whole data while performing union, I get an error. It works fine if I take only a single column, but error is thrown when I take two or more columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and remember Tables should have the same structure.

```
SELECT *
FROM   schema1.tbl_user
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   schema2.tbl_user
```

And for large number of schemas you can use the following stored procedure. This will generate the UNION query dynamically and you can add the conditions to filter out the schema and table names.

```
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @schema_name NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @gettable CURSOR
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(100)
SET @query=''
SET @gettable = CURSOR FOR
SELECT name,
       schema_name(schema_id)
FROM   sys.tables

OPEN @gettable
FETCH NEXT
FROM @gettable INTO @table_name, @schema_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @query = @query + 'SELECT * FROM ' + @schema_name + '.'+ @table_name + ' UNION ';
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @gettable INTO @table_name, @schema_name
END
CLOSE @gettable
DEALLOCATE @gettable
print @query;
```

Comment: This is a simple solution if you have only 2 or 3 tables. I am talking about a thousand schemas and new schemas can be added or the existing schemas can get deleted.

Comment: updated the answer. Please check. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I do not know how to dynamically create a query using stored procedures and when I tried it failed to work. I have already got the schema tables this way : SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'.'+'fk_tbluser'
AS SchemaTable
FROM sys.tables

Comment: I have updated the answer with stored procedure code.